# Self Join Performance in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to perform a complex self-join on a table in SQL Server. the table has almost 2 million rows. The self join on this table is taking more than hour. Can we rewrite the query using window functions?

Below is sample data.

```
create table #Student(Code int, ExternalId varchar(20),FieldName varchar(100))

Insert into #Student(Code,ExternalId,FieldName)
values(100,'213-654','Address'),(100,'213-654','Address'),(100,'213-654','Address'),
(200,'675-238','Name'),(200,'675-238','Name'),
(300,'456-632','Gender'),(300,'456-632','Gender'),(300,'456-632','Gender'),
(400,'874-438',NULL),(400,'874-438',NULL)
```

Below is the query I am using.

```
SELECT  St1.Code , St1.ExternalId  ,'FieldName' AS Discrepancy
FROM #Student St1    
  INNER JOIN #Student St2    
   ON St1.Code = St2.Code    
   AND St1.ExternalId = St2.ExternalId  
   where St1.FieldName <> St2.FieldName   
    AND St1.FieldName IS NOT NULL    
    AND St2.FieldName IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Both SQL Server 2008 and 2012 are *completely unsupported*, why have you tagged both and which are you *really* using?

Comment: As a side note, as well, your `IS NOT NULL` clauses are redundant; you check both columns aren't `NULL` in the clause `St1.FieldName <> St2.FieldName`.

Comment: change the CREATE TABLE to: `create table #Student(Code int, ExternalId varchar(20),FieldName varchar(100)), index s(Code,ExternalId,FieldName))`, and see if that makes a change. Please report back with the found change.

Comment: Please provide your desired results for the sample data given

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure but from what I understand you're attempting to get the
`Code` and `ExternalId` of students that have more than one non-null `FieldName`.

To do that, you can use a simple `group by` query with a `having` clause on `count(distinct...`) as shown below.
I can't guarantee it because your query and sample data returned an empty recordset but you should test it with better sample data.

```
SELECT  Code ,ExternalId  ,'FieldName' AS Discrepancy
FROM #Student 
WHERE FieldName IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Code, ExternalId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT FieldName) > 1
```